# Laravel Sanctum protecting a model with a composite primary key

Tags: php, laravel, token, composite-primary-key, laravel-sanctum

I want my Laravel 8 application to handle tokens for IOT devices interfacing an API.

My original model had a composite primary key like this, and note the composite primary key.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use App\Models\Tenant;
use App\Traits\Multitenantable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Device extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory;

    protected  $fillable = [
        'device_id', 'tenant_id', 'name', 'key', 'secret'
    ];

    // protected $primaryKey = 'device_id';
    protected $primaryKey = ['device_id', 'tenant_id'];
    protected $table = 'devices';
    public $incrementing = false;


    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime',
        'updated_at' => 'datetime',

    ];

    public function tenant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tenant::class, 'tenant_id');
    }

    protected function setKeysForSaveQuery($query)
    {
        $query
            ->where('device_id', '=', $this->getAttribute('device_id'))
            ->where('tenant_id', '=', $this->getAttribute('tenant_id'));

        return $query;
    }
}
```

When trying to create the Token in the controller I got the error

ErrorException
array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

The controller that handles the devices login looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Models\Device;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class DeviceAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // return "Entro al login";
        $validate = $request->validate([
            'tenant_id' => 'required|integer',
            'key' => 'required|string|max:100',
            'secret' => 'required|string|max:100'
        ]);

        $device = Device::where('key', $validate['key'])->where('tenant_id', $validate['tenant_id'])->first();
        if (!$device || !Hash::check($validate['secret'], $device->secret)) {
            return response(['message' => 'invalid login'], 401);
        } else {
            $token = $device->createToken($device->name);
            $response = [
                'message' => 'Login successful',
                'device' => $device,
                'token' => $token,
            ];
            return response($response, 200);
        }
    }
}
```

I finally solved my problem removing the composite primary key of devices and defining the primary key like this in the Device.php

```
    protected $primaryKey = 'device_id';
```

Is there a way to use Sanctum tokens with a composite primary key model?

Thank you

Ernesto Pareja